# Deleting object of a state array in React using id

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

When I console.log(id) it give me the index of the object in the array and not the id I was trying to assign to it with the function that creates the object. So my question is how do I pull out a specific key value pair out of my arrays object and use it to make sure that I am deleting the right object?

Also I am really really new to programming.

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function App() {
    const [text, setText] = useState([]);
    const [textMaster, setTextMaster] = useState({
        paragraph: "",
        id: nanoid(),
    });

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const copy = [...text];
        copy.push(textMaster);
        setText(copy);
    };

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        handleSubmit(e);
    };

    const handleClickDelete = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const newText = text.filter((text) => text.id !== id);
        setText(newText);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                </a>

                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Essay:
                        <textarea
                            name="item"
                            key={textMaster.id}
                            type="text"
                            value={textMaster.paragraph}
                            onChange={(e) => setTextMaster(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
                        Add new text
                    </button>
                </form>
                <ul>
                    {text.map((item, id) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <li key={id}>{item}</li>
                                <button onClick={() => handleClickDelete(id)}>
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                            </>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function returns the index as the second parameter, the `text` is not an object it wont have the `id` in it.

```
{
    text.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                <button onClick={() => handleClickDelete(index)}>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </>
        );
    })
}
```

Then, in the delete function use the index to remove the text from the array updating the state with the new Array.

```
const handleClickDelete = (index) => {
    const newTexts = [...text]
    newTexts.splice(index, 1) // To remove the index 
    setText(() => newTexts);
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks @Woohaik. So I updated the code and it now removes the first index?

Comment: Now it removes always the first index ?,  try logging the "selectedTextIndex",  and see if is different of undefined.

Comment: If for some reasson returns undefined, now the id is passing correctly you could use     const newText = text.filter((text) => text.id !== id);

Comment: Okay so i logged the "selectedTextIndex" and it returns index "0" for all? So I am not passing it correctly?

Comment: Check if the id is actually different for all texts, before doing the "findIndex".

Comment: Okay it is different indexs for all the texts

Comment: Do a console.log(text) before the "findIndex". Lets see if all texts have different  id or if at least is different from undefined this should explain why. check the id not the index.

Comment: okay this is returning "undefined"    ...                                                                                         const handleClickDelete = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const selectedTextIndex = text.findIndex((text) => text.id === id);

Comment: does the "text" variable has the id key ?  Not having it explains the undefined id value

Comment: Ohhhh no ... const [text, setText] = useState([]);
    const [textMaster, setTextMaster] = useState({
        paragraph: "",
        id: nanoid(),
    });

Comment: text is the [] array that hold the textMaster {paragraph: "" id: nanoid()} objects.

Comment: This is why you wont get the id inside the `handleClickDelete` you could try to use the index now you dont need the id, or using another squema for the `text` that have the id as well, why separete it into two , text and textMaster?

Comment: Trying to learn controlled components

Comment: Okay when I console.log(selectedTextIndex) it returns -1

Comment: That means it is not finding it, -1 is the default value returned by findIndex if nothing matchs. Ill edit the answer

Comment: Before always got the index 0 because id was always undefined so there is always a match, of `undefined === undefined ` so the first value will be returned, try the edited one if with index but the object doest have id I cannot find something that is not there